# Show that f is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{2x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$, unless $x=y=0$, and $f(0,0)=0$. Define $\phi (t)=(t,at)$. Show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}f(\phi(t))=0.$ Thus $f$ is continuous on any straight line through $(0,0)$.

I started of by substituting: $f(\phi(t))=\frac{2at^3}{t^4+a^2t^2}$. However, I got stuck after this. When I try dividing every term by $t^4$, I end up with a limit of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. How should I proceed?

Comment: Notice that if $a = 0$, then $f(\phi(t)) = 0$ anyway. If $a\neq 0$, then pulling a $t^2$ out of the numerator and denominator gives $$f(\phi(t)) = \frac{2at}{t^2+a^2}$$
This might be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my hint slightly, we consider $f(\phi(t))$, and $f(\psi(t))$, where $\phi(t) = (t,at)$, $\psi(t) = (bt,t)$.

First, $f(\phi(t)) = \frac{2at^3}{t^4+a^2t^2}$, $f(\psi(t)) = \frac{b^2t^3}{b^4t^4+t^2}$.
$$\lim_{t\to 0} f(\phi(t)) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2at^3}{t^4+a^2t^2}= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2at}{t^2+a^2}$$
$$\lim_{t\to 0} f(\psi(t)) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2b^2t^3}{b^4t^4+t^2}= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2b^2t}{b^4t^2+1}$$
Notice that if either $a=0$ or $b=0$, then the first limit (respectively the second) are both $0$. Also, if $a\neq 0$, 
$$\lim_{t\to 0} f(\phi(t)) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2at}{t^2+a^2} = \frac{0}{a^2}=0$$
And this covers every single possible line passing through $(0,0)$. (The only one you might have been missing is the vertical line, which is covered by considering $f(\psi(t))$ for the case $b=0$.)

Comment: Is it necessary to consider your parameterization $\psi (t)$? As for all $b\neq 0$ $(bt,t)$ describes the same straightline as $(t,\frac{t}{b})$

Comment: The only reason I included it at all was for the case $b=0$. Everything else, as you said, is exactly covered. But there is no way to cover the vertical line $x=0$ with the parametrization $\phi(t)$.

Comment: I suppose it is an overcomplicated construction, but it was done in this manner for generality.

Comment: Generality is always better to aid understanding I agree :) just wanted to make it clear for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

So using Nicholas's hint we can safely assume $a\neq0$ and then
$$\lim_{t\to 0}f(\phi (t))=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2at}{t^2+a^2}=0/a^2=0$$